# Serving web-sockets and web-pages from the same port

Tags: java, websocket, netty

Using Java's Netty, can you serve HTTP requests and web-sockets from the same port?

I thought that the whole point of using HTTP "upgrade" for web-sockets was to make this so.

But I can't find even a clear simple example of a web-socket server in Netty, let alone how to mix it into an HTTP server.  (The [websocket example](http://static.netty.io/3.5/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/WebSocketServer.html) puts all its effort into serving a favicon to non-websocket connections and omits actually having much of a conversation with a client.)

Comment: I was under the assumption that you run the WebSocket server on a different port but the connection is setup via port 80 with switching protocols.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, something makes me think you didn't read the example thoroughly enough. It

1. demonstrates combination of regular HtTTP requests and websocket requests
2. it does *not* serve the favicon resource (it returns 404 Not Found), and
3. exchande websocket text frames with the client